# Django. Cannot load picture from ImageField

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to upload a picture from ImageField in template, but it is not displayed. Code and screenshots will explain better.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/veracrypt1/django/pycaba/pycaba/media/'
```

models.py

```
image = models.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
def thread(request, boardname, thread_id):
    board = boardname
    thread = thread_id
    op_post = get_object_or_404(Posts, board=board, id=thread_id)
    return render(request, 'board/thread.html', {'op_post':op_post})
```

thread.html

```
{% extends 'board/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="op_post">
    <img src="{{op_post.image.url}}">
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

thread.html source in browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1v7i.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Django version are you using? Have you included [static file urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development) in you url patterns?

Comment: Thanks. Including static urls helped